# Automorphism of unit disc which maps two points on the boundary to $1$ and $-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, automorphism-group, mobius-transformation

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1\}$ and its boundary $\mathbb{T}=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$. If $\lambda \ne \mu$ are two points in $\mathbb{T}$, then I need to show that there is an automorphism $v$ of $\mathbb{D}$ such that $v(\lambda)=1$ and $v(\mu)=-1$.

I tried the following : Any automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ is of the form $v(z)=\eta \frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$ for some $\eta \in \mathbb{T}$ and $a \in \mathbb{D}$. If we put $v(\lambda)=1$ and $v(\mu)=-1$, we get the following:

$\eta (\lambda-a)= 1-\overline{a}\lambda \quad \text{and} \quad \eta (\mu-a)= -1+\overline{a}\mu$.

If we try to solve for the value of $a$, we get that $(\lambda-a)(-1+\overline{a}\mu)= (1-\overline{a}\lambda)(\mu-a)$. But I have not been able to solve this equation.

Comment: I don't know what's right approach to solve this but if we want to do some brute force calculations then it will be easier if we try to find an automorphism that fixes $1$ and sends $-1$ to $\mu\lambda^{-1}$(call it $\alpha \in \mathbb T$).

Comment: Easier: Do the calculation for the upper half plane.

Comment: If $v$ is an automorphism of $\Bbb D$ you can't apply it to $\lambda$ and $\mu$ since they are not in $\Bbb D$.

Comment: @jjagmath: Automorphism of the unit disk are exactly the Möbius transformations of the form $v(z)=\eta \frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$ with $|\eta| = 1$ and $|a| < 1$ (as OP said). So what you say is of course true, but they extend in a natural way to rational functions on the (extended) complex plane, and in particular to continuous functions on the closed disk.

Comment: @MartinR All the three approaches are clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By rotating the initial configuration we can assume that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are symmetric with respect to the real axis and lie in the closed right halfplane, i.e.
$$
 \lambda = x+ iy \, , \mu = x-iy \, , \quad 0 \le x < 1 \, , 0 < y \le 1 \, .
$$
The equation
$$
(\lambda-a)(-1+\overline{a}\mu)= (1-\overline{a}\lambda)(\mu-a)
$$
then becomes
$$
2x (1+|a|^2) + 4 \operatorname{Re}(a) = 0 \, .
$$
The symmetry of the rotated configuration suggests to look for a *real* solution $a$, which then must satisfy the equation
$$ \tag{$*$}
 x (1+a^2 ) + 2a = 0 \, .
$$
If $x = 0$ then $\boxed{a=0}$ is a solution. Otherwise $(*)$ is a quadratic equation in $a$ with the solutions
$$
 a = \frac{1 \pm\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} = \frac{1 \pm y}{x} \, .
$$
Exactly one of these solutions, namely $\boxed{a = \frac{1-y}{x}}$ is in the range $(0, 1)$.

So on any case we have found a real value $a \in [0, 1)$ such that the corresponding Möbius transformation $T(z) = \frac{z-a}{1-az}$ satisfies $T(\lambda) = - T(\mu)$. It only remains to append a rotation with a factor $\eta$ of modules one to get $v(\lambda)=1$ and $v(\mu)=-1$.

---

There is also a geometric solution: Find $a \in \Bbb D$ such that the four points $\lambda, a, \mu, 1/\bar a$ lie on a circle $C$. $T(z) = \frac{z-a}{1-\bar az}$ maps $C$ onto a line $L$ through the origin. Then $T(\lambda)$ and $T(\mu)$ lie on the boundary of the unit disk *and* on $L$, so that $T(\lambda) = - T(\mu)$. Again it only remains to compose that with a rotation of unit modulus.

---

Yet another approach: Choose $\nu, \zeta \in \Bbb T$ such that $\nu \ne \lambda, \tau$ and $\zeta \ne 1, -1$. There is a unique Möbius transformation $T$ which maps $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ to $1, -1, \zeta$, respectively. $T$ maps $\Bbb T$ only itself, so that either $T$ or $1/T$ is an automorphism of the unit disk with the desired properties.

Comment: Thank you Martin! The last approach seems pretty clear to me.